# TypeError raised when trying to find prime factors with dict()

Tags: python

This raises a `TypeError` exception and I can't figure out why. Thanks for any suggestions!

```
import math

def get_pf(X, pf):
    for n in range(2, int(math.sqrt(float(X))) + 1):
        if X % n == 0:
            pf[n] = pf.get(n, 0) + 1
            get_pf(X/n, pf)

    pf[X] = pf.get(X, 0) + 1

pf = {}
N = input()    
get_pf(N, pf)

print(str(pf))
```

Comment: Please paste the actual exception and traceback, rather than just saying there is one. Also, tell us what input you're using.

Comment: Please show the complete error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
    if X % n == 0:
```

`X` is a string, because that's what `input` returns. So, `X % n` is trying to do string formatting. If there are no `%` characters in the string, this will raise:

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

You're already doing `float(X)` to solve this exact same problem in the line directly above. All you have to do is do the same thing again.

---

However, it's probably simpler to pass the number as a number in the first place: `get_pf(float(N), pf)`.

---

Also, are you sure you really *want* a float here? What are the prime factors of 2.71319? If you want integers, use `int`, not `float`.

Answer (score 1):

`input` returns a string in Python 3, so you need to convert it to an int:

N = int(input())